# answerCallbackQuery QUERY_ID_INVALID

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

This command:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot(bot.token)/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=1066578811231371872
```

Gives me this error:

```
{
ok: false,
error_code: 400,
description: "Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID"
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this must be the answer:

https://api.telegram.org/bot(bot.token)/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=1066578811231371872

The answer has to be send back in a few seconds. I dit copy/pased within 10 seconds but that seems to be to long.